# Writing bash conditionalwith nested piped command

Tags: bash

The following bash command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l
```

prints:

> 0

What I want is, when the result is indeed 0, to print FAILURE to the terminal.

This is what I've tried:

```
if [ aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l = 0]; then echo FAILURE; fi
```

but nothing is printed. it looks like it is waiting for more input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html):

```
if [ $(aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo FAILURE;
fi
```

or in a line:

```
if [ $(aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep _SUCCESS | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo FAILURE; fi
```

---

Better solution as "@steeldriver" suggested use using grep's exit status :

```
if aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep -q _SUCCESS; then echo FAILURE; fi
```

or:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir | grep -q _SUCCESS || echo FAILURE
```

Comment: steeldriver's solution does not work. There is a BrokenPipeError.